# iOS App ID - In App Purchase Disabled (Can't be enabled)

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-id

I have created beta version of my app and uploaded it to iTunes Connect for TestFlight testing without any problems.

Later, I decided to implement **In-App purchase**. I visited apple page with identifiers and found out that there is already **explicit App ID** for my app. I wanted to edit my explicit App ID and enable In-App purchases.

[image: Disabled in-app purchases]

When I clicked "Edit" button, I found out that In-App Purchase checkbox is grayed out and cannot be edited.

[image: IAP cannot be enabled]

The In-App Purchase should be enabled by default according to the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html):

> Explicit App IDs are App IDs whose Bundle Identifier portion is a string without the wildcard ("*") character. Furthermore, they are automatically registered for in-app purchase and Game Center

Any idea how to enable the In-App Purchase? (I would like to use the same bundle ID).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am not sure if it was some sort of bug or I really resolved the issue.

Here are the steps I have done:

**1.)**
Enable In-App Purchase in Capabilities

[image: IAP Capabilities]

**2.)** Upload new version of the app to the TestFlight testing. *I have checked my AppID afterwards, but In-App purchase was still disabled.*

**3.)** Wait... Relax, enjoy the weekend. :)

**4.)** Check your App ID after the weekend

[image: Enabled In-App Purchase]